# Parsing Webpage with BeautifulSoup Doesn't Give Full Page Contents

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the description 'Enjoy the power to creat and control...' from this webpage: https://www.origin.com/zaf/en-us/store/the-sims/the-sims-4.

When I parse the page with Beautifulsoup, the page source doesn't include the description and I'm not sure why.

```
handle = 'sims 4'

query = handle + " origin.com"  # enter query to search
print(query)
for topresult in search(query, tld="com", lang='en', num=10, stop=1, pause=2):  
    print('Query Successful:' + handle)

page = requests.get(topresult)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days. I've also tried using Selenium and the Chrome driver but get a similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests and BeautifulSoup will not work for this because the page is loaded dynamically with javascript. That is why you cannot find the description. Selenium webdriver should work just fine. I wrote some code to get the description.

---

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.origin.com/zaf/en-us/store/the-sims/the-sims-4')
desc = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//p[@ng-bind-html="::$ctrl.description"]')))
print(desc.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for you help LuckyZakary!